# Will the pointer to __FILE__ remain valid after moving out of scope?

Tags: c++, debugging

If I want to pass `__FILE__` to an object, do I need to make a copy of the string or can I just store its pointer as `const char*`?

I'm guessing that I need to make a copy since I think it will free itself once it moves out of scope.

Does the pointer to `__FILE__` provide any guarantees?

Comment: It is a preprocessor thing - so make a copy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__FILE__` expands to a normal string literal. So as long as you are only reading it, you can just use a `const char*` like

```
const char *filename = __FILE__;
```

As string literals have static storage duration, the pointer will remain valid throughout the whole program.

If you want something modifiable, you need a copy and manage its lifetime yourself.

For a complete list of predefined standard macros and information about what they expand too, have a look at the *"Predefined macros"* section on [this documentation page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

As [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) correctly pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646965/will-the-pointer-to-file-remain-valid-after-moving-out-of-scope#comment62774179_37647002), different expansions of `__FILE__` may or may not yield the same address, that is:

```
const char *f1 = __FILE__;
const char *f2 = __FILE__;
assert(f1 == f2);              // May or may not fire
```

I am not sure when that would bite you, but it's good to know I guess.

Comment: Note that if you refer to `__FILE__` from two different places in your code, both will refer to a static array object containing the same string (assuming no `#line` directives), but they may or may not be the same object with the same address.

Comment: This answer is actually not correct in all cases. When a dynamically loaded library is unloaded (for example, using dlopen/dlclose), all pointers to its `__FILE__` literals will become invalid.

Comment: @SanderMertens Okay, but "unloading" part of your program is beyond the scope of both the standard and this answer. It is not part of the "lifetime" concept this Q/A is about.

Comment: @BaummitAugen agreed, though people running into the problem I describe will likely end up on this page, so I thought it'd be good to capture it.

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` is a preprocessor macro that is replaced by a string literal when the preprocessor runs. Any use of it is as if you typed `"filename.c"` into your source code. It is not a pointer, it does not have scope, and is not freed -- those are compile-time and run-time concepts which do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that I need to make a copy since I think it will free itself once it moves out of scope.

No, it's a character literal. It doesn't ever *move out of scope*.

> Does the pointer to `__FILE__` provide any guarantees?

Yes. As mentioned it's deduced as a `const char[]` character literal type, and that indicates you don't need to care about memory management.